# Writing a file to nexus 4 device is not working

Tags: android, file-io

I am trying to create a file on device using the following code

```
private void createFileOnDevice(Boolean append) throws IOException {

        File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (Root.canWrite()) {
            File LogFile = new File(Root, "log.txt");
            FileWriter LogWriter = new FileWriter(LogFile, append);
            out = new BufferedWriter(LogWriter);
            Date date = new Date();
            out.write("Logged at"
                    + String.valueOf(date.getDay() + "-" + date.getHours()
                            + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
                            + "\n"));
        }
    }
```

The code works fine, when i run on devices which has android version 2.3.5 to 4.3 it creates a file.

But when i run the same app on Nexus 4 , which has latest android version(4.4.2, kitkat), i am unable to create the file. Also, I am not getting any error.

How do i fix it??..

Thanks in advance :):)

Comment: there is pretty simple explanation `Root.canWrite()` returns `false`

Comment: @selvin thanks :), but why i am not getting on other version. why on 4.4.2, can you please explain the reason?

Comment: i have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be the lack of external storage on a nexus 4...

When you are testing, are you testing it in debug mode? If so your operating system will have access to the storage on the nexus 4 and not the phone. Try testing it when the phone has access to the storage and see what happens then...

Comment: You can't have a memory card in a nexus 4. It doesn't have a slot for one. Try installing the app on your phone, taking it out of debug mode , dosconnect the phone from the PC, then test it again

Comment: What was the solution to your problem? Please mention here if you accepted this answer.